# How to remove Appicon Badge, ios10, swift

Tags: ios, swift

I can add a badge to the AppIcon, I just cannot remove it.

I have a notification helper class, with a refresh badge number function, as shown below:

```
import UserNotifications

class NotificationHelper {

...

    //fetch all notifications, and update the tabBarController
    func refreshTabBarBadge(tabBarController: UITabBarController) {
        ... some Core Data related stuff to set badge

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        if badge > 0 {
            content.badge = badge as NSNumber
        }
        else {
            content.badge = 0
            content.badge = nil
        }
        print("set app icon badge to: \(badge)")
    }
```

When I print the output, I see:

```
set app icon badge to: 1
```

This sets a badge on the AppIcon.

Then when I trigger an event that causes the `badge` variable to decrease I see:

```
set app icon badge to: 0
```

Yet, when I background the app and check the icon, the badge remains, set to 1.

Its as if `content.badge` is not working at all. In the Apple documentation it says if the badge number is 0, it will remove the badge, but this is not the case. As you can see, I also try setting it to `nil` afterwards.

How do I remove the badge from the AppIcon?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

set badge number = 0.
like `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0`

Comment: It works, thanks. I'll accept your answer when it lets me. there appears to be a 10 minute threshold.

Answer (score 0):

I've used

```
content.badge = -1
```

to remove the badge.